# How to Add to cart from external domain using Post Method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

I have an app which needs to collect various product options and then make a post request to an external url (https://my-shop.myshopify.com/cart/add) and then redirect to that site with the items added to cart.

Unfortunately I can't simply use a cart permalink as I need lineitems to be included. So far I have this in my controller which successfully makes the post but doesn't redirect to the shopify site.

```
   def add_to_cart

    @urlstring_to_post = 'https://my-shop.myshopify.com/cart/add'

    #submit and get a result

    @result = HTTParty.post(@urlstring_to_post.to_str, 
    :body => {:id => '15158758855', 
    :add => 'Add to Cart'
    }.to_json,
    :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } )

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you get back from the Shopify API (e.g. what are the contents of `@result`), but you can perform a redirect like this:

```
class CartItemController
  def create
    # .. some stuff to add an item to the cart ...
    redirect_to "/your-custom-url"
  end
end
```